# Remap CTRL + 7 to the character {

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, manjaro, keyboard-layout

How do I remap the character <kbd>{</kbd> to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>.

The reason is that <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> is awkward to press for me and would be easier by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>. Also I want to set it up the same way of getting <kbd>{</kbd> on both a MAC keyboard and a regular keyboard.

I have tried looking at [xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xmodmap), but I cannot figure out how to do it with that program.

I have played around with the example `$ xmodmap -e "keycode 46 = l L l L lstroke Lstroke lstroke"` and getting keycodes via `xev` and made change like remapping <kbd>a</kbd> to be <kbd>{</kbd>.

i have also tried with [input-remapper](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper) without luck.

I use a [Danish keyboard](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/Computer_keyboard_Danish_layout.svg).

Here is my keycodes:

```
Ctrl + 7
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x1e3, subw 0x0, time 12553850, (-832,-181), root:(448,940),
    state 0x4, keycode 16 (keysym 0x37, 7), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1f) ""
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1f) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x1e3, subw 0x0, time 12553954, (-832,-181), root:(448,940),
    state 0x4, keycode 16 (keysym 0x37, 7), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1f) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Sorry I can't help with the answer, because with KDE I can simply choose Mac keyboard layout and only need to add another AltGr key to the left side (because there are more characters than `{` that require AltGr keys for both hands. Please note that people with a US keyboard can't understand your question, because they have `[` and `]` keys next to `P` and can access `{` and `}` with the shift key. They probably never heard of an AltGr key.

Comment: I believe "control" is not a modifier you can do this with - but could you sacrifice a control key or other key to be a Mode_switch or ISO_Level3_Shift (AltGr)? Caps lock often gets nominated, the [ArchWiki has some examples that might help](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xmodmap#Templates). I only have VNC access to my home server right now, half my modifiers don't work so I can't usefully test anything :(

Comment: you may try `xdotool`